# How to keep a random occurring botton inside the body(Or inside any div)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Made a button using html, css and js which occurs randomly on the page.But i want the button inside the body tag and it keeps getting out.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>SReflex</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="random">1 </button>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
*{
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;

}

button.random {

    /* looks of the button */
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    border: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;

  
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

JS CODE:

```
let temp= document.querySelector(".random");
temp.addEventListener("click",change);

function change(){
    let posx = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    let posy = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    let posz = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    temp.style.left= posx + "vw";
    temp.style.top= posy+ "vh";
    temp.style.right= posz+ "vw";
}
```

How do i make the button to not go off screen, i want the page to not include the scroll bar.

Comment: If the position is `1000vh` or `1000vw` that means 10 times the height/width of the screen. (100 is the whole screen). So you could change the random values to `100` minus the width/height of the button itself.

Comment: I tried that already but still the button was going off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do so, it works for the **body** or for a containing **div** because it's related to parent size.
check out the snippet.

```js
let temp= document.querySelector(".random");
temp.addEventListener("click",change);
let maxw = temp.parentElement.clientWidth - 50;
let maxh = temp.parentElement.clientHeight - 50;
function change(){
    let posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxw));
    let posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxh))
    temp.style.left= posx + "px";
    temp.style.top= posy+ "px";
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;

}

button.random {

    /* looks of the button */
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    border: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;

  
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>SReflex</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="random">1 </button>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

the **-50** is to make sure it doesn't cross the edges, you can edit that to suit your needs.

Comment: How did you know that -50 is required? Like why not -40 or -100? And what exactly is the unit of the -50.

Comment: not necessary a -50, I told you can edit that but it should be around at least half the width of the button for x and half the height for y so the element doesn't be 100% out.

Comment: Whats the unit of that -50 ?

Comment: in this case in px, you specify the unit at the end + "unit", I used pixels because the client width and height returns a number in pixels, you can use other units but you need to convert the client width and height first.